# Trying to make shape using nested loops python 3

Tags: python, loops, nested

I am trying to make the following shape using python 3 nested loops:

```
 * 
 * * 
 * * * 
 * * * * 
 * * * * * 
 * * * * 
 * * * 
 * * 
 *
```

I write this code:

```
star = " * "
shape = star
i = 1
print(shape)
while i == 1:
    if len(shape) == 13:
        break
    elif len(shape) < 13:
        shape += star
        print(shape)

while i == 1:
    if len(shape) == 3:
        break
    elif len(shape) >= 3:
        shape = shape[:-3]
        print(shape)
```

and the output is this:

```
 * 
 *  * 
 *  *  * 
 *  *  *  * 
 *  *  *  *  * 

Process finished with exit code -1
```

I am a beginner in python. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @OP What do you mean by nested loops? Your included code doesn't have nested loops, and neither does the example I posted below (partly because I didn't read the prompt carefully enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
shape = "* "
i = 1
for i in range(1,10):
  if i < 6:
    print(shape*i)
  else:
    print(shape*(10-i))
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates the desired output

```
shape = "*"
i=1
while i <= 10 :
    if i < 6:
        print(shape*i)
        i+=1
    else:
        reverse = 10-i
        print(shape*reverse)
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you need to use a while loop? The following is a much simpler way to accomplish the same task:

```
for stars in (range(1,6) + range(4,0,-1)):
    print(' * ' * stars)
```

But, assuming you had to use while loops and string concatenation, why wouldn't you tie the while loop to the length explicitly instead of using break:

```
print(shape)
while len(shape) < 13:
    shape += star
    print(shape)

while len(shape) > 3:
    shape = shape[:-3]
    print(shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple (and not too code-efficient) solution:

```
star = " * "
for i in [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]:
    print(star*i)
```